# How to do I make X.org listen to remote connections on a Kubuntu 22.04 system on port 6000?

Tags: networking, 22.04, kubuntu, remote-access, xterm

There are several solutions which I have already tried proposed.   But none specifically addresses Kubuntu 22.04..   I've tried them all but the closest one to working is the use of socat to connect the tcp socket to a unix socket.

My ubuntu system is a vmware VM running above Fedora 25 Linux.

With socat applied I CAN successfully open an xterm on the vm display with:

```
xterm -display 127.0.0.1:0
```

but

```
xterm -display  172.16.82.172:0   (where this is the IP address of the vm)
```

yields

```
2023/12/31 17:02:30 socat[3667] N accepting connection from AF=2 172.16.82.172:47228 on AF=2 172.16.82.172:6000
2023/12/31 17:02:30 socat[3667] N forked off child process 4778
2023/12/31 17:02:30 socat[3667] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:6000 
2023/12/31 17:02:30 socat[4778] N opening connection to AF=1 "/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"
2023/12/31 17:02:30 socat[4778] N successfully connected from local address AF=1 "\xEE\xEE\xEE\xEE\xEE\xEE"
2023/12/31 17:02:30 socat[4778] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [5,5]
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 172.16.82.172:0

2023/12/31 17:02:30 socat[4778] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF 
2023/12/31 17:02:30 socat[4778] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF 
2023/12/31 17:02:30 socat[4778] N exiting with status 0

westall@kubuntu-22:~$ 2023/12/31 17:02:30 socat[3667] N childdied(): handling signal 17
```

Does anyone know a way to specify the authorization protocol?